# Removing while iterating on sequences in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set

Could any one please explain how [removing items from a list](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=l=%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D%0Afor+i+in+l%3a%0A++++if+i%3C6%3a#we+think+that+in+2nd+step+i=2+but+actually+i=3%0A++++++++print+i%0A++++++++l.remove%28i%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0) works and why [removing items from a set](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=l=%7B1,2,3,4%7D%0Afor+i+in+l%3a%0A++++if+i%3E0%3a%0A++++++++l.remove%28i%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0) doesn't work?

Though we can iterate both lists and sets, why can't changes be made to sets? Is it because sets aren't ordered?

Comment: Read the documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

**Under the hood SET implementation is totally different from LIST.**

**List:** Python’s lists are variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style linked lists. The implementation uses a contiguous array of references to other objects, and keeps a pointer to this array and the array’s length in a list head structure.

**Set:  a set uses a hashtable as it's underlying data structure. Just like a dictionary but with dummy values. And we are using the key as element in set like list.**

**`Dictionaries or Set`** implement a **tp_iter** slot that returns an efficient iterator that iterates over the keys of the dictionary. During such an iteration, the **dictionary or set** should not be modified, except that setting the value for an existing key is
allowed (deletions or additions are not, nor is the update() method). This means that we can write

So, while you are iterating a set

```
>>> for i in s:
...     s.pop()
...
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
>>>
```

But if you use `while` you can delete or update it:

```
>>> s = set(range(5))
>>> while s:
...     s.pop()
...     print s
...
0
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
1
set([2, 3, 4])
2
set([3, 4])
3
set([4])
4
set([])
>>>
```

[You can see here in the source code:](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a87f284e14ea/Objects/setobject.c#l854)